# iphone cocos2d multiple audio files, best approach?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer

I have found already some similar [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193844/play-multiple-audio-files-with-avplayer) on this, but would like to investigate further and find out what's the best library and approach to use for a game made with Cocos2d v1 with the following requirements:

- swap one soundtrack with another one, interlacing them (the current one lowers the volume whilst the other one increases)
- have multiple audio effects (like bullet shoot sounds different for each enemy)

[Cocosdenshion](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:faq) seems to be the best approach for a cocos2d game (rather than using avplayer). Would you agree?

Thanks!

Comment: I use Cocosdenshion and works without problems

Comment: I use cocosdhenshion without any issues, although i dont attempt interleaving. When the game switches from a logical scene to another, i fade-out and fade the new scene in, where the background music fades out and in with the scene itself.

Comment: Did anyone try to fade in and fade out  multiple times the same two tracks? (interleaving).. @Setrio, have you tried to interleave?

Comment: I prefer ObjectAL over CocosDenshion, makes a number of things easier, if not trivial.

Comment: @mm24 noup, i never tried that

Comment: @LearnCocos2D why would you prefer ObjectAL for that? I saw that both can do audiometering, and interlacing but wanted to understand.. is there anywhere a comparison table among all libraries? I did found a good description of ObjectAL but nothing comparing all. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up this question.. I did use "CDXPropertyModifierAction.h" library which allowed me to reference to the shared SimpleAudioEngine of the application as well as the CDAudioManager.

Although, having 4 tracks and several .caf effects, I have a consierable memory footprint. I read the comment of @LearnCocos2D and I will now try integrating ObjectAL and do some benchmarks on performance and memory footprint.

I will add comments to this answer, and please do feel free to do so as well to contribute.

Thanks a lot for your comments..