# How to play multiple Audio Files simultaneously using AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, audio, avplayer

I am trying to play multiple audio files using 2 AVPlayer instances, but one of the player stops for a fraction of a second rather than playing all audio files simultaneously. 
The logic of the program is as follows:

`var player: AVPlayer?` will stream an audio file from my database. On its own is playing perfectly.

`fileprivate var countPlayer: AVPlayer?` plays the count number of the current item being played by `var player`. The count is a sequence of 1 to 8 and for each digit I am storing/sandobxing a .wav file locally such as 1.wav, 2.wav...8.wav.

When current time of `var player` is at a certain time, `countPlayer` is triggered and it plays one of the local file 1.wav, 2.wav..etc.

The problem is that when the `var countPlayer` starts playing, it causes the background AVPlayer, namely `var player` to stop for a fraction of a second, similar to what's described in this comment:

[Play multiple Audio Files with AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193844/play-multiple-audio-files-with-avplayer#comment7213305_6193844)

```
   var player: AVPlayer? //plays the song
   fileprivate var countPlayer: AVPlayer?  // plays the count number of song



   private func addBoundaryTimeObserver(tableIndexPath: IndexPath) {


    let mediaItem = mediaArray[tableIndexPath.row]

    guard let url = URL(string: mediaItem.mediaAudioUrlStringRepresentation ?? "") else {return}
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    var timesToTransverse = [NSValue]()

    //convert string representation of times elements to array
    let timesRecorded: [String] = mediaItem.timesRecorded.components(separatedBy: ",")

    // Build boundary times from arrayOfBeats keys
    let timeDoubles: [Double] = timesRecorded.compactMap {timeString in
        if let second = Double("\(timeString)") {
            return second
        }
        return nil
    }

    guard timeDoubles.count > 0 else {return} //unexpected

     timesToTransverse = timeDoubles.map { second in
        let cmtime = CMTime(seconds: second, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        return NSValue(time: cmtime)
    }

    guard timesToTransverse.count != 0 else {return}

        guard let playerCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? PlayerCell else {return}

       startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

    timeIndex = 0
    player?.play()
    player?.rate = Float(initialPlaybackRate)



    // find the index of time
    //reset timeObserverToken
    // call a function with the new times sorted


    // Queue on which to invoke the callback
    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    // Add time observer
    timeObserverToken =
        player?.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: timesToTransverse, queue: mainQueue) {
            [weak self] in


            //because there are no time signature changes, we can simply increment  timeIndex with + 1 every time `addBoundaryTimeObserver` completion handler is called and subscript timesToTransverse with timeIndex in order to get the subsequent timeInSeconds
            guard let strongSelf = self, strongSelf.timeIndex < timesToTransverse.count else {return}

            let timeElement = timesToTransverse[strongSelf.timeIndex]
            strongSelf.timeInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeElement.timeValue)

                //show progress in progressView
                let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.duration)
                let cmtimeSeconds = CMTime(seconds: strongSelf.timeInSeconds, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))

            //Total time since timer started, in seconds
            strongSelf.timeInSeconds = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - strongSelf.startTime

            let timeString = String(format: "%.2f", strongSelf.timeInSeconds)
            strongSelf.timeString = timeString


            //use reminder operator to determine the beat count
            let beat = (strongSelf.timeIndex + 1) % 8 == 0 ? 8 : ((strongSelf.timeIndex + 1) % 8)


            //play the beat count : 1, 2, ...8
          self.preapareToPlayAudio(beatCount: beat) 

            /*
             0: (0 + 1) % 8 = 1
             1: (1 + 1) % 8 = 2
             6: (6 + 1) % 8 = 7
             7: (7 + 1) % 8 = 0
             */

            strongSelf.timeIndex += 1
    }
}//end addBoundaryTimeObserver


 //prepare determine what wav file to play 
   private func preapareToPlayAudio(beatCount: Int) {

  switch beatCount {  
    case 1:
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "1", withExtension: "wav") else {return}
        playWith(beatCountURL: url)

        //7 more cases go here .....
    default: print("unexpected case here")
    }   
}//end play(beatCount: Int)



     private func playWith(beatCountURL: URL) {

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: beatCountURL)
        countPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        countPlayer?.play()
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off using AVAudioPlayerNode, AVAudioMixerNode, AVAudioEngine. Using these classes you won't have problems like you have right now. It's also not that difficult to set up.

You can check out my gist, in order to play the sounds in your Playgrounds you would need to put audio files into Resources folder in Project Navigator:
https://gist.github.com/standinga/24342d23acfe70dc08cbcc994895f32b

The code works without stopping background audio when top sounds are triggered.

Here's also the same code:

```
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class AudioPlayer {
var backgroundAudioFile:AVAudioFile
var topAudioFiles: [AVAudioFile] = []
var engine:AVAudioEngine
var backgroundAudioNode: AVAudioPlayerNode
var topAudioAudioNodes = [AVAudioPlayerNode]()
var mixer: AVAudioMixerNode
var timer: Timer!
var urls: [URL] = []

init (_ url: URL, urls: [URL] = []) {
    backgroundAudioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
    topAudioFiles = urls.map { try! AVAudioFile(forReading: $0) }

    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()

    engine.attach(mixer)
    engine.connect(mixer, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)
    self.urls = urls
    backgroundAudioNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    for _ in topAudioFiles {
        topAudioAudioNodes += [AVAudioPlayerNode()]
    }
}

func start() {
    engine.attach(backgroundAudioNode)
    engine.connect(backgroundAudioNode, to: mixer, format: nil)
    backgroundAudioNode.scheduleFile(backgroundAudioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

    try! engine.start()
    backgroundAudioNode.play()

    for node in topAudioAudioNodes {
        engine.attach(node)
        engine.connect(node, to: mixer, format: nil)
        try! engine.start()
    }
// simulate rescheduling files played on top of background audio
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [unowned self] in
        for i in 0..<1000 {
        sleep(2)
        let index = i % self.topAudioAudioNodes.count
        let node = self.topAudioAudioNodes[index]
        node.scheduleFile(self.topAudioFiles[index], at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        node.play()
        }
    }
    }
}

let bundle = Bundle.main
let beepLow = bundle.url(forResource: "beeplow", withExtension: "wav")!
let beepMid = bundle.url(forResource: "beepmid", withExtension: "wav")!
let backgroundAudio = bundle.url(forResource: "backgroundAudio", withExtension: "wav")!
let audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(backgroundAudio, urls: [beepLow, beepMid])
audioPlayer.start()
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any method available on AVAdudioEngine like `addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: timesToTransverse, queue: mainQueue) ` that would enable me to play certain audio nodes? As you can see in my current implementation, `addBoundaryTimeObserver` gives me a callBack for each time traversed. Many thanks

Comment: I have another gist where I show how to get current time of playback: https://gist.github.com/standinga/f79232adb15e1f867ad1637f47c61003 using Timer.scheduledTimer, in one of my apps I'm using multiple AVPlayer like you do (for playing beep sounds) and I can tell you that sometimes they will fade-in sounds (cutting transients) so I think AVAudioPlayerNode is better solution for playing short sounds etc.

Comment: Problem is that I need to play a certain sound at a specific times while the background sound is being played. When currentTime of AVPlayer is matched to one of the elements in my array listed below, I need to play 1.wav, 2.wav...up to 8.wav. `"13.38,13.83,14.03,14.18,14.33,14.48,14.83,15.18,15.37]"`
This array represents the times when each beat count must be played in a sequence from 1 - 8.
Example play: 1.wav: 13.38, 2.wav at: 13.83, 3.wav at: 14.03  and so on. Is there such function such as `addBoundaryTimeObserver` in AVAudio Engine so that I can play specific nodes at specific times?

Comment: With the current implementation you are suggesting, I see no way of playing the specific sounds at different specific times. Please see video of what I am trying to achieve https://youtu.be/5okBjG9L7Hw

Comment: You could use AVAudioPlayerNode playing over AVPlayer (using .addBoundaryTimeObserver), or AVAudioPlayerNode playing over AVAudioPlayerNode scheduling nodes with node.scheduleFile. In both versions you could use prepared times at which nodes should play. You can check updated gist: https://gist.github.com/standinga/f3e303d504f770a33496941137a68eef there are two functions one using AVPlayer + AVAudioPlayerNodes and second AVAudioPlayerNnodes only.

Comment: I have tried to adapt your answer to my initial case, but it turns out I cannot use AVAudioFile(forReading:) on a remote file.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688901/url-is-nil-in-avaudiofile . Do you have any suggestion on that? Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear only the background file is remote, the countdown files are stored locally?

Comment: Hey I just checked the gist I posted in comments on Feb 13. https://gist.github.com/standinga/f3e303d504f770a33496941137a68eef it let's you use AVPlayer and works with remote mp3, specifically the func playWithAudioPlayerAndNodes(), I just played remote file in the background using this gist. I can update it later if you still have problems, please let me know!

Comment: I still can't get it to play remote or local mp3 file.  Please see gist and screenshot with error https://gist.github.com/bibscy/1c30aa6ebb21f9734d1466c978a127a6 . Screenshot https://imgur.com/RKkh5rP

Comment: Hey the crash was because the init was allocating both AVPlayer and AVAudioFile, here's a gist with removed unrelevant code. You just need to replace url with your url. I tested with the url you provided in screenshot and it works fine.
https://gist.github.com/standinga/b9287a1c6f4ecc1f952e9d14b36aecaf

Comment: I know you answered this question, but I am trying to add a new feature to play only certain nodes and when I do the switch, the nodes end up playing multiple times simultaneously. They kind of overlap. I added a video link so that you can see the app in action with the issue. https://youtu.be/HGm1hJX1Oiw  and the gist with the code https://gist.github.com/bibscy/8aef8406e278d07646f911ecf17dfebd

Comment: Hey, can you please post it and a new question, including parts of the code in the question? This way maybe somebody else will answer.

Comment: Hi, nobody has answered in the past week https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126570

Comment: Hey, will try to look into it! I was quite busy last 2 weeks, plus the code you pasted there is on the longer side. It's also quite involved logic going on there. You might be better off refactoring the nodes into separate custom classes which would hold their own state.